# React-Router Link entire (inline-)block instead of just text?

Tags: css, react-router

I'm implementing a simple React component ([example 2 here: navigation menu](http://tutorialzine.com/2014/07/5-practical-examples-for-learning-facebooks-react-framework/)) but adding in React-Router to have clicks on the navigation menu activate different routes. I have it working almost properly: clicking on the text of the button takes you to a different route, but *clicking elsewhere* in the `inline-block` just changes the style (activating `class="active"`) but doesn't change the route (the `onClick` listener is on the `li` tag).

As you can see below, you can click on the `Services` *text* to activate the Services route, but if you click in the `About` block but not on the text of the block itself, it will register `About` as active but not change the route.

[image: screenshot of app]

Here is the relevant code in React and my css:

class Navigation extends React.Component {

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {chosenIndex: 0, tabs: ['Home', 'Services', 'About', 'Contact us']}
    this.selectTab = this.selectTab.bind(this)
}

selectTab(e, i) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({chosenIndex: i})
}

render() {
        let buttons = this.state.tabs.map((tab, index) => {
            return (
                <li key={index} className={index === this.state.chosenIndex ? 'active' : 'inactive'} onClick={event => this.selectTab(event, index)}><Link to={nameToPath(tab)}>{tab}</Link></li>
            )
        })
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        {buttons}
                    </ul>
                    <Match exactly pattern="/" component={Home} />
              <Match pattern="/services" component={Services} />
              <Match pattern="/about" component={About} />
              <Match pattern="/contactus" component={ContactUs} />
              <Miss component={Home} />
            </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
```

CSS:

```
html{
    font:24px normal Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#626771;
    background-color:#fff;
}

body{
    padding:60px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul{
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#eee;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#7B8585;
    transition:0.3s;
    font: bold 14px Arial;
}

ul li:hover {
    background-color:#beecea;
}

ul li.active {
    background-color:#41c7c2;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7b8585;
    display: block;
}

ul li.active a {
    color: #fff;
}

p {
    padding-top:15px;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

Comment: Didn't fully investigate, but I'm pretty sure this page contains all you need for this kind of stuff: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/05-active-links

Comment: Please include your `selectTab` function code. I am unsure if you are saying that that is supposed to do navigation between pages or just highlight the tabs in your app.

Comment: @PaulS I just added it to the question. Right now clicking in the tab but not on the text only changes the highlight; navigation only happens when clicking on the text itself. I'd like it to navigate if clicking anywhere in the navigation "box."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be simple enough to fix with CSS by adding `display: block` to the CSS of the `<a>`.

**Edit:** The padding on the `<li>` should also be moved to the `<a>`. `display: block` does not extend the `<a>` into its parent's padding, so clicking on the parent's padding will not register the click event with the `<a>`. If you move the padding to the `<a>`, however, then clicking on the padding *is* clicking on the `<a>`, so the navigation will happen as expected.

The navigation only happens when you click on the text because only the text is part of the `<a>` tag rendered by the `<Link>`.

By default, the `<a>` is rendered inline (see the style difference between the `<li>` and the `<a>` in the snippet below).

```css
li {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 50px;
}

a {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href='#'>Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

However, when you add `display: block;` to the anchor element's CSS and move the padding from the list element to the anchor, you see that it expands to take up the entire `<li>`.

```css
li {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
}

a {
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href='#'>Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I did have `display:block;` in the `a {}` but it still doesn't fix the problem...

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to take a closer look at this then. Will update if I figure out that there is some other issue.

Comment: that totally did it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the whole container tag but you will be able to to do it just by adding`padding: relative` to the text or the text you've applied  on....